# Printing Sepcific values on a Two Dimensional Array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have created a 2D Array as follows

```
String names [][] = new String [5][2];

for(int i=0; i<names.length;i++){
    System.out.println(names[i][1]);
    System.out.println(names[i][0]);
}
```

And the OutPut:

```
Jack  | 2013
Peter | 2012
Cham  | 2011
Jayce | 2013
Robin | 2011
Jax   | 2013
```

I'm required to print values containing `2013` in this array . Please help.

Comment: this will not work.... if you have 2 rows, the second value length should be 2

Comment: and please should us ehat you have tried yet

Comment: You dont have a second column when the length of the "column"-array is 1

Comment: Please post your code that you try and the error you face if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can compare String in loop `names[i][0].equals("2013")`

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (names[i][0].equals("2013")) {
                System.out.print(names[i][1] + "   ");
                System.out.println(names[i][0]);
            }
        }
```

**Output**

```
jack   2013
Jayce  2013
Jax    2013
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the rows containing "2013" you need an if in your loop

```
for(int i=0; i<names.length;i++){
    if(names[i][0].equals("2013") {
        System.out.println(names[i][1]);
        System.out.println(names[i][0]);
    }
}
```